# Why does meteor hang while using WebApp & send npm package to serve custom files?

Tags: google-chrome, meteor, npm, send

I've created a custom upload / serve mechanism to manage media files for a meteor app.

## The problem

The whole application hangs after ~800 - 4000 (it varies from system to system) files are served to a browser

## Simplified serve code

```
var idx = 0;
var send = Meteor.npmRequire('send');

WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res /*, next*/ ) {
    sendFile(req, res, '/penken.jpg');
});

var sendFile = function(req, res, urlPath) {
    var lidx = idx++;
    console.log(lidx, 'requesting', urlPath);

    send(req, urlPath, {
        root: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads',
        maxAge: 20 * 60 * 1000
    }).pipe(res);
};
```

### Notes

- I don't know if this is a specific `meteor` issue or it is a `send`,  `WebApp` etc.
- I couldn't pinpoint the problem - since it is hard to reproduce and node-inspector cannot debug a hung application
- Interestingly enough if I run wget 10000 times using the following bash line:

  ```
  for i in `seq 10000`; do wget http://localhost:3000/uploads/penken.jpg -qO /dev/null; sleep 0.01; done
  ```

  The issue doesn't manifest itself

## Sample project to exemplify the issue

Find it at: https://github.com/albertmatyi/meteor-hangs

### To try it out

1. Clone the project
       `git clone https://github.com/albertmatyi/meteor-hangs.git`
2. Enter its folder
       `cd meteor-hangs`
3. Run the server
       `meteor`
4. Open up chrome and navigate to (you should see a picture)
       `http://localhost:3000/`
5. Open up the Inspector and disable the cache
   [image: Disable cache]
6. Refresh the page ~810-4500 times (may vary) - Simply keep your finger on the refesh button (`F5`, `Ctrl + R` or `Cmd + R`)
    The console will show how many time the resource was requested and served
7. **Result:** Meteor hangs and will not serve any other client

#### [GitHub meteor issue ref](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2787)

Answer (score 1):

This *probably* happens because you are using middleware that has blocking file I/O ops. The thing is for every page load, Meteor initially has to go through each middleware handler and run it before a page can be served.

The reason you are probably having this issue is that the operation you are doing is I/O intensive and its blocking the rest of the middleware from operating while it is awaiting the previous tasks to complete. (Keep in mind javascript is asynchronous but file I/O is blocking).

There isn't an easy way passed this. Immediate ideas that come to mind are to somehow use a memory buffer or something for this, or ensure that it only runs for the specific path (such as `/upload` instead of for all paths. This way you would not be inconvenienced so much.

The reason the wget operation works is there is no other javascript called. For each page load meteor has a couple of dozen javascript files for each module it has that the browser will call (which in turn each file request will call the middlware too). It will wait for the js before the page is served.

What I would suggest, to keep things simple, is to only do the `sendFile` operation if the route matches a specific pattern, such as `/upload`. This way it is not run if you use `http://localhost:3000`.

Something a bit like this (which will only work on `/upload`

```
var url = Npm.require('url');

WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    if(path != '/upload') next()

    sendFile(req, res, '/penken.jpg');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1), unfortunately I have tested this also with a longrunning ui test (4hrs ~2100 media requests) and I was using path matching, but the result was the same: the server halted afterwards. And only a new restart fixed it. In the sample above is I've taken out any other logic, that I've thought is unrelated to the problem. Normally this is what I use for url matching:
`var re = /^\/uploads((?:\/[\w_\-.%]+)+)(?:\?.*)?/.exec(req.url); if (re) { sendFile(req, res, re[1]);  } else { next();  }`

Comment: @Matyas do you use a SSD or HD?

Comment: SSD. And after the hanging I have only ~25 filedescriptors open. In the longrunning test I've seen that some filedescriptors were still open for mp4 files (larger range requests - i guess)